# Rails error message on views folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, undefined

Ive been going through this for hours and i cant seem to find the problem. Im doing a simple contacts form in rails , this is a tutorial im following so bear with me. I get the following error message :

> undefined method `name' for #

I have this in my DB/migrate file:

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  create_table :contacts do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.string :email
    t.text :comments
    t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

this on my `contacts_controller.rb` file:

```
  class ContactsController < ApplicationController
    def new
      @contact = Contact.new
    end

    def create
    end
  end
```

and this is on my `pages_controller.rb`:

```
  class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def homepage
    end

    def about
    end
  end
```

This is my html :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<div class="well">
  <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :comments %>
      <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
  <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which tutorial are you following?

Comment: @RichPeck its a course i purschased called CoderManual

Answer (score 2):

Did you run your migration?

If not, do so:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

This will create the `contacts` table in your database (which has the `name` column along with other columns `email` and `comments` that you're using while building your form). Also, re-start your rails server and then you should be able to use your form code without any problem.

Comment: i did use that many times  and also db:drop , but neither worked. The table in the db is already created , i manually created it . I didnt use rails generate.

Comment: If you go to your rails console, and type: `Contact.first` or `Contact.count`, what do you see?

Comment: @K M Rakibul , it works now i just simply re did all the work from the beginning.

Comment: Somehow the `contacts` table was missing in your database and that'w why you were getting that error. Happy to know that your issue is fixed now. Feel free to accept the answer if you found it useful. To know more how accepting answers work, see this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You have probably not migrated your table.

In your console run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then restart your server and try again.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers summed it up well - you need to *migrate* your `contacts` table:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

You'll want to [read up on Rails migrations here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migration-overview).

---

As an aside,

**Pages**

I don't know which tutorial everyone seems to be following, it's telling you to use specific actions for *static* pages, which IMO is pretty bad practice (especially in the long run).

A *much* more versatile (and "Railsy*) solution is to put the content for the data in the database, which you can then call with a *model* - allowing you to have a single `show` view for all your pages:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :pages, only: [:show]

#app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
class PagesController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @page = Page.find params[:id]
   end
end

#app/views/pages/show.html.erb
<%= @page.title %>
<%= @page.body %>
```

You'd have to create another migration for the *pages* datatable, as follows:

```
$ rails g migration CreatePages

class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  create_table :pages do |t|
    t.string :title
    t.text :body
    t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

$ rake db:migrate
```

---

**HTML**

Your current HTML can be a lot more efficient:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="well">
      <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
         <% attributes = {name: "text_field", email: "email_field", comments: "text_area"} %>
         <% attributes.each do |attr,val| %>
            <div class="form-group">
               <%= f.label attr.to_sym %>
               <%= f.send(val, attr.to_sym, class: 'form-control') %>
            </div>
         <% end %>
         <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```